# CakePhp - blocking the site with Auth - how?

Tags: cakephp-1.3, authentication

I want to block the website completely - using the Auth.
in the "normal" usage it is redirecting the user to the login page while it can still see the layout. i want to prevent it.

I want the unauthorized guest to see ONLY the login form

---

#### edit

I saw an option to use an empty layout in the login function, but i guess that there is another way, is there?

#### edit

Bumping, anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch to a different layout in a `beforeFilter` if the user is not logged in:

```
function beforeFilter() {
    if (!$this->Auth->user()) {
        $this->layout = 'anonymous';
    }
}
```

Put this in the AppController.

The other way around works as well of course: if the user is logged in, use your "full" layout and make `default.ctp` something minimalistic instead.

Comment: lol, thanks, this is my solution that i am trying to avoid. guess it's the only way so far. thanks again